# Wrong UILabel Hebrew text

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nsxmlparser, hebrew

Good day, the problem is this - I have to get a string from the server:
 שיעור ראשון - הרב חגי לונדין but when try do NSLog i saw - ׳¢׳¨׳•׳¥ ׳׳׳™׳¨ - ׳׳•׳׳׳¦׳™׳ ׳“׳£ ׳”׳‘׳™׳×
or \U05f3\U201c\U05f3\U2018; I try set Hebrew language to my UILabel;

```
cell.titleLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Please Help Me.